# Timezone region not found issue in date conversion for jasper

Tags: datetime, casting, timestamp-with-timezone

My requirement is need to convert the input date values which is in yyyy-MM-dd (user input value) format to GMT and we have our own timezone table which stores all the timezones values. So we need to convert input value(yyyy-MM-dd) to GMT as we are storing the values in GMT only. I have tried with FROM_TZ, CAST functions but getting timezone region not found issue.
Can anyone please suggest the changes accordingly.

Here attaching the some sample code (this is user input value).
start_time >= to_date(to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp('2017-09-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS AM') , tz.offSet) at time zone 'GMT'),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MI AM'),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MI AM')

Thanks,
Sant

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my case :

```
-- returns a date value of a date converted in UTC and formated
cst_timestamp_fmt      constant varchar2(20) := 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS';

function fn_Date_To_UTC_Formated(p_date date) return date is
   begin
      return to_date(to_char(
                   to_timestamp(
                    sys_extract_utc(
                           to_timestamp(
                                   to_char(p_date,
                                           cst_timestamp_fmt
                                           ),
                                   cst_timestamp_fmt
                                       )
                                   )
                               ),
                    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
                            ),
                 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
                    );

end fn_Date_To_UTC_Formated;
```

and to test it:

```
declare
cst_timestamp_fmt      constant varchar2(20) := 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS';
 function fn_Date_To_UTC_Formated(p_date date) return date is
       begin
          return to_date(to_char(
                    to_timestamp(
                        sys_extract_utc(
                               to_timestamp(
                                       to_char(p_date,
                                               cst_timestamp_fmt
                                               ),
                                       cst_timestamp_fmt
                                           )
                                       )
                                ),
                        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
                        );

    end fn_Date_To_UTC_Formated;
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(' sysdate : '||to_char(sysdate, cst_timestamp_fmt));
   dbms_output.put_line(' result  : '||to_char(fn_Date_To_UTC_Formated(sysdate),cst_timestamp_fmt));
end;
```

result is

```
 sysdate : 20-SEP-17 15:20:09
 result  : 20-SEP-17 13:20:09
```

hope that can help.